# How to know if my Android activity is transition from 3rd party activity in onResume()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In Android app, we transition from activity to activity. I want to know if my activity is called from 3rd party activity, i.e. either

1. from other apps, via intent
2. from background, e.g. open my app, resume and switch from my app

So in the onResume() method of all of my activities, how to check and exclude those invoked from my own activities?

Answer (score 0):

For instance you could include in the intent's bundle some special parameter when starting activity from inside of your app. So if intent's bundle does not contain that parameter then its not from your app. Any time you could check intent:

```
onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey("MY_VERY_SPECIAL_PARAM"))
      // this intent is yours...
}
```